# How can I make a this of $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code:

```
$(.clsname).on("click", function(){
    do_something($(this));
});

function do_something(sth){
    /*
     * in here sth equals $(this)
     * and I want to get "this" of "$(this)"
     *
     * EX: this.value = "some value";
     * I know I can do that like sth.val("some value");
     * but I need to do that by following the first version (using "this")
     */
}
```

As you see, my question is commented in the code above. How can I do that?

Comment: Why not `$(this).val()`?

Comment: Just use `sth[0]`

Comment: Why not do something like `do_something($(this),this)`? But I believe that `sth[0]` is the "correct" answer, though in general you would need to be aware of the possibility that it is empty and trying to access the first element could throw.

Comment: $('.clsname').on("click", do_something); then no need to pass sth and this will be the dom element. https://jsfiddle.net/5mg13tgk/

Comment: @SeanWessell . . . Ah, thank you for the point `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
sth[0]
```

which will convert into a `DOM` object

You can also use the `get` method on the jQuery object.

`sth.get(0)` // Extracts the native `DOM` element from jQuery object.

will also give you the same result.

Comment: Just for my information, It is impossible to make a `$(this)` of `this`, right?

Comment: Why don't you just pass `this` from the function. If you need a `jQuery` object you could just encase it with `$`

Comment: You could just try this approach

`$(.clsname).on("click", function(){
    do_something( this ));
});

function do_something(sth) {
    // sth is a native DOM element 
   
   let jQueryThis = $(sth);

}`

Comment: @MartinAJ There would be nothing stopping you from calling `$` on anything you wanted. `$` is a function like any other.

Comment: with `$` and parenthesis, right?

Comment: @MartinAJ That is correct !

Comment: btw, do you know why my question earned 3 downvotes?

Comment: @MartinAJ hahah. I am not really sure. Sometimes when people feel it has been answered already or if it is trivial they tend to do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is get the elements that the jQuery object contains, without the jQuery wrapper. If you just have a single element, you can do either `sth[0]` or `sth.get(0)`. If you have multiple elements you can use `sth.toArray()`.